# Good undergraduate level textbook on elliptic curves

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

I'm taking a Elliptic Curves class as an undergraduate math major. We are using "Ellpitic Curves" by  Lawrence C. Washington.

I'm struggling and would like some other resources I could use to help supplement my study. I ordered "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves" by Silverman and Tate.

Ive done some searching but most of the recommendations ive found are more advanced and I think would be over my head. Is there anything else I could potentially get something out of? Many thanks

Comment: @DietrichBurde That other question references the book I already said I bought, and then the accepted answer is about a more advanced book, which I specifically do not want. I'm trying to find information on if there are other appropriate texts for my level

Comment: The other post also recommends Silverman and Tate. This is for undergraduates, so certainly not too advanced. I think this is the best. Of course there are other great texts, e.g., by William Stein. Search here for recommendations at the multiple duplicates for elliptic curve books.

Comment: @XRBtoTheMOON, while I wholeheartedly agree and recommend Silverman and Tate, I'd like to point out the book I wrote on elliptic curves for the AMS. I am always hesitant to recommend my own book, but I wanted to point it out to you because I wrote it with undergrads in mind, and the goal is to provide a bird's eye view of the theory of elliptic curves. http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/stml-58

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo Thank you so much for the recommendation. I just ordered a copy!

Comment: Feel free to email me if questions arise.