# Structure of the group of points of order $m$ on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

I am reading the book [An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography](https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/MathCryptoHome.html) and in the chapter about Elliptic Curves and Cryptography there is the proposition below.

It is about the structure of the group $E(\mathbb{C})[m]$ of points of order $m$ and its counterpart for finite fields:

[image: Proposition]

That proposition seems quite unexpected and is not proven in the book. I can't figure out how we might have such a result.

Would it be possible to give the **idea / intuition of a proof** in the simplest terms?

If not, what would be a roadmap to be able to fully understand the reasons for this result?

Comment: There are very detailed proofs in the standard books on elliptic curves. Have a look at the [references](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705283/good-undergraduate-level-textbook-on-elliptic-curves?noredirect=1&lq=1) for elliptic curves. It is as popular in elliptic curves as Jordan form in linear algebra. So it is best to read a book proof yourself. I suppose the undergraduate book by Silverman and Tate is very good for this purpose.

Comment: Perhaps better than a proof are a few examples with a computation. Start, say, with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742066/the-group-structure-of-elliptic-curve-over-mathbb-f-p). You can search for more examples.

Comment: Did you hear about the isomorphism between complex elliptic curves and complex tori (ie. things like $\Bbb{C/(Z+iZ)}$) ? Note that the $m$-torsion of $\Bbb{C/(Z+iZ)}$ is evident. This lifts to the $E(\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p)$ case.

Comment: @reuns I read that there is a correspondence between the complex tori and an elliptic curve via the Weïerstrass elliptic function. Although I don't know why this correspondence should be a group isomorphism.

Also, I don't know what you mean by "this lifts to..." and how we can deduce anything related to the finite fields case.

Comment: The map $(x,y)\to (x,y)+P$ on $E(\Bbb{C})$ gives a Riemann surface automorphism of $\Bbb{C/\Lambda}$ without fixed point. With things like Liouville theorem it is not too hard to see that it must be $z\to z+\phi^{-1}(P)$ on $\Bbb{C/\Lambda}$.

Comment: Also, when you say that this _lifts_ to the $F_p$ case, what are you referring to? Can that aspect be understood without any notion of scheme theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I will also answer my question since I read [Kirwan's book on complex algebraic curves](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/complex-algebraic-curves/1DA895ACD18127789DC05F212A8330E7) and I thought it was quite enlightening (regarding the complex case).]

I will state a few things about **complex** elliptic curves and then discuss the case of an arbitrary field using arguments from logic.

###### Complex elliptic curves "are" torus

It's not too difficult to see that the [Weierstrass ℘ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function) is a meromorphic function on the torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ (seen as a compact Riemann surface).

Studying a bit compact Riemann surfaces, we learn that meromorphic functions on them are quite restrained. More specifically in this case, combining $℘$ and $℘'$ in a way that eliminates the poles yields a holomorphic function on the torus, which must be constant as per compacity and maximum modulus principle (or Liouville Theorem).

Thus, we can show that we have an isomorphism of Riemann surfaces between a torus and a complex elliptic curve (both being parametrized by $\Lambda$).

###### This correspondence is also a group isomorphism

We have a Riemann surface isomorphism $z \mapsto (℘(z), ℘'(z))$ (extended by mapping the pole to the point at infinity $\infty$ of the curve).

The expression of that isomorphism shows that integrating the differential form $\frac{dx}{y}$ along a path from $\infty$ to a point $P$ we can recover $z$, giving an inverse map $u$ from the curve to the torus.

If $D$ is a line in $P_2(\mathbb{C})$, it intersects a curve in 3 points $A, B, C$ and we'd like to show $f(D) := u(A) + u(B) + u(C) = 0 \mod \Lambda$ (*).

The "trick" here is to first show that $f(D) = 0$ for all lines $D$ of the form $by+cz=0$.

Those lines $D_{[b:c]}$ are parametrized by $P_1(\mathbb{C})$ in such a way that we get a holomorphic map $[b:c] \mapsto f(D_{[b:c]})$.

By Liouville theorem, this map must be constant, hence equal to its value on $[0:1]$ which is $0 \mod \Lambda$ as it corresponds to the case $A = B = C = \infty$.

We get $f(D) = 0$ for any line $D$ by considering lines of the form $\alpha x + \beta (by+cz)$ and reiterating the same kind of construction varying $[\alpha:\beta] \in P_1(\mathbb{C})$.

This shows the correspondance between the torus and the elliptic curve is a **group morphism**.

###### Subgroup of points of order $n$

The result stated in the question is obvious in the case of complex elliptic curves, given the group isomorphism with a torus.

###### Elliptic curves over an algebraically closed field $K$

In this case, we can't refer to Riemann surfaces and we don't have such thing as a torus.
However, the result stated about the subgroup of points of order $n$ is an algebraic result.

In particular, it can be stated in $ACF_0$ (the first order theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$) (*)

As this theory is complete, this result is true over **any** such field of characteristic $0$.

By compacity argument (of first order logic), this result is still true in characteristic $p > 0$ except for potentially finitely many characteristics.

The result expressed in the question make the restriction on $p$ more precise, which is possible by studying from scratch the problem in an algebraic way.

(*) Actually, for a fixed $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, the sentence *The group of points of order $n$ has cardinal $n^2$ for all $n \leq n_0$* is expressible in the language of fields and from that we get the structure of those subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer (a). I think the easiest way to see this is analytically, i.e. seeing $E$ as a complex tori, say $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z} + \tau \mathbb{Z}$ with $\tau$  a purely imaginary complex number of positive imaginary part (any complex lattice is isomorphic to one of those, by scaling essentially). Now, it is enough to look at the $m$-torsions of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. These $m$-torsions are the points $c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $mc \in \Lambda$, modulo $\Lambda$. That is the points in $\frac{1}{m} \mathbb{Z} + \frac{\tau}{m} \mathbb{Z}$ modulo $\Lambda$. Now it shouldn't be too difficult to see this is $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

I see you also have trouble to understand why the map $\phi: \mathbb{C}/\Lambda \rightarrow E(\mathbb{C})$ that allows us to see $E$ as a complex tori is an isomorphism (of complex Lie groups). For the details, you can look at Silverman's standard book "The arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Proposition 3.6 on page 170 of the second edition. Perhaps, I can briefly explain why this is an homomorphism. Take $c, c' \in \mathbb{C}$ then there exists an elliptic function (doubly periodic meromorphic function) with period $\Lambda$, say $f$, such that the principal divisor associated to $f$ is $$div(f) = (c+c') - (c) - (c') + (0).$$ Now, one can show that any such elliptic function $f$  is a rational function of $\mathcal{P}(z)$ and $\mathcal{P}'(z)$ where $\mathcal{P} $ is the Weierstrass function associated to $\Lambda$. That is, we can write $f(z) = g(\mathcal{P}(z), \mathcal{P}'(z))$ where $g(X,Y)\in \mathbb{C}(X,Y)$. Let us denote $x, y$ the image of $X$ and $Y$ respectively in the coordinate ring of $E$ (that is under the projection $\mathbb{C}[X,Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(h(X,Y))$ where $h$ is the polynomial defining $E$). Now, we can treat $g$ as an element of the function field of $E$, i.e., $g(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}(x,y) = \mathbb{C}(E)$. We get a principal divisor on $E$ $$div(g) = (\phi(c+c'))-(\phi(c)) - (\phi(c')) +(\phi(0)).$$
This can only happen if $div(g) = \mathcal{O}$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the neutral element of $E$ as a group (note that the last summation is a summation of elements of $E$). That is, $\phi(c+c') = \phi(c) + \phi(c').$

As a remark on (b), the only possible obstruction to not get (a) is issues of inseparability, that is if the multiplication-by-$m$ map, denoted $[m]$, is inseparable, which is not the case as long as $p$ does not divide $m$. Again, you can consult Silverman, Corollary 6.4, he also gives the case when $p$ divides $m$.

Hope this helps a bit.